# What happened to warp drives destroying the universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, ftl-drive

I remember a TNG episode where some scientists said that warp drives were causing a lot of damage to subspace. At the end of the episode Star Fleet decided that warp speeds would be restricted to warp 5 except for emergency situations.

Of course the next episode they were cruising along at warp 7.

Is this ever mentioned again in Star Trek?

Comment: I heard that the Voyager was designed in such a way that it worked around this problem.  I think there is an article on memory alpha about it.  Great question BTW.

Comment: The episode was [Force of Nature](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Force_of_Nature_%28episode%29) Season 7 Episode 9.  This article on [Warp Field](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Warp_field) has a brief paragraph on the subject, both on [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org).

Comment: @Mark, I remember hearing the same thing, the whole deal with VOY's nacelle's swinging in and out was meant to lessen the impact.

Comment: Since when has a negative effect on the environment ever stopped anyone from driving faster? ;-)

Comment: I had always thought that the restriction was being placed upon regions of space that are more susceptible to damage, but I just re-watched the final scene in that episode and it certainly does appear to be a "global" speed limit. Huh.

Comment: If star-fleet is like any other bureaucracy they probably just had the numbers on the dials changed, So warp 9 is now Warp 5.

Comment: What happened to pollution destroying the Earth? There was a  'global financial crisis' and now the only narrative in politics is economic growth. Ironically, recessions have been more successful at reducing carbon dioxide emissions than any international treaty.

Comment: @MikeBoers At the end of the episode, Captain Picard reads the Federation Council directive: "Until we can find a way to counteract the warp field effect, the Council feels our best course is to slow the damage as much as possible. Therefore, areas of space found susceptible to warp fields will be restricted to essential travel only, and effective immediately, all Federation vessels will be limited to a speed of – Warp 5? – except in cases of extreme emergency." The directive could be interpreted to mean only in "areas of space found susceptible to warp fields" is warp travel restricted.

Comment: @RobertF That comment should be an answer.

Comment: Destroying the universe would be a good way to end the series with a grand finale.

Comment: ["I can't drive warp 5"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvV3nn_de2k)

Comment: The mechanism described by the brother and sister team - analogized by Data as "wearing out a carpet by walking on it over and over" - would never apply to any appreciable area of space, so the episode never made any sense in the first place.  Between the sheer scale of interstellar space and the expansion of space itself, no warp field would ever be generated in the same section of space twice.  Ever.  Terrestrial environmental concerns don't work when applied to the scale of the galaxy.

Comment: Because it was simply bad writing from a team that was largely burnt-out by the time of the seventh season, hence so many poorly thought out ideas and such an over-reliance on senseless technobabble in so many of the last season episodes.  The seventh season of TNG, and the complete run of Voyager, contained more types of made up new "particles" and "fields" and "gravimetric whatsits" than the rest of the entire franchise combined.

Comment: @AaronLitz You can't scare me with your technobabble.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It was never addressed in canon.

The episode to which you refer, "Force of Nature", occurred in the last season of *The Next Generation* at a time when most of the effort in storylines was geared towards *Star Trek: Voyager* and *Deep Space Nine*: the developers of those shows didn't particularly focus too much on the continuity issues introduced as *The Next Generation* was wrapping up. Indeed, even *The Next Generation* writers ignored or found ways around it for the remainder of the season.

However, according to [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Force_of_Nature_%28episode%29#Continuity):

> According to the unpublished VOY Season 1 edition of the Star Trek: Voyager Technical Guide, by Rick Sternbach and Michael Okuda, it was suggested that because of the variable geometry pylons, warp fields may no longer have a negative impact on habitable worlds as established in this episode.

But since the manual was never published, it's not canon. Alternative theories include:

- In *Deep Space Nine*, the Dominion War was more important than an environmental concern.
- In *Star Trek: Voyager*, they were so far away from the Federation and getting home was such a huge priority, any non-core regulation artificially limiting their ability to travel was summarily dismissed.

It's also interesting to note that the issues raised in "Force of Nature" are referenced, indirectly, in the last season Voyager episode, "Renaissance Man", when the Hierarchy attempt to trick the Voyager crew into ejecting their warp core because they entered an area that's occupied by people who believe warp drives disrupt subspace.

Comment: It's also worth noting that TNG struggled over its run trying to move from an episodic series (which was Roddenberry's intention with TOS and TNG) into an ongoing continuity.

Comment: In a nutshell "You must construct additional pylons"

Comment: @IG_42: LOL....

Comment: It is mentioned again in S07E12 at ~1:30. The enterprise is authorized to "exceed warp speed limitations for the duration of the assignment".

Answer (score 39):

Early in the episode [*The Pegasus*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Pegasus_%28episode%29) Picard is given orders to search for the titular ship.  The admiral who gives him the order also gives him authorization to ignore the warp speed restriction, for the course of the mission.  This episode was 3 episodes after *Force of Nature*, the episode where the 'speed limit' is introduced.

It was never mentioned during DS9.  During VOY, they may have mentioned it during a couple of episodes where there are regions of space that are unsafe to traverse via Warp Drive ([here](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Renaissance_Man_(episode)) and [here](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Omega_Directive_(episode))), but I don't recall offhand.

Comment: Good catch, I remember it being mentioned but had little hope of finding which episode!

Comment: I wonder, however, if warp above 5 is mentioned subsequent to Force of Nature without it being an emergency?

Comment: I think they mentioned the limit (as in, "we're ignoring it on purpose") for the following 2 or 3 episodes, then dropped it.

Comment: @sanity not sure what the emergency was, and unfortunately I don't have access to TNG season 7 to find out.

Comment: It's also mentioned in passing in the episode [Pegasus](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Pegasus_(episode)), when Picard is given authorization to exceed warp speed limitations "for the duration of this assignment".

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is that it's not addressed again, beyond the end of TNG.

### In-universe explanation

Quoting from the [Star Trek Encyclopedia (2nd Edition)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia)

> *The council further ordered Federation ships throughout the galaxy to
>   restrict their maximum speed to warp 4.7. (TNG: Force of Nature).
>   The Starship Enterprise-D and other ships observed the "warp speed
>   limit" for the remainder of Star Trek: The Next Generation. **After
>   that, it was assumed that Starfleet was able to develop a more
>   "environmentally friendly" warp drive, so the speed limit was
>   evidently lifted.***

One can assume that if the fix was actually quite trivial, the other major powers would have had no qualms about enacting it.

### Out of Universe explanation

As to why the decision was made to simply gloss over the problem, the simplest way to look at it is that continuing to insist upon '*warp-speed restrictions*' would have demanded regular explanation (adding to the length of scripts) without actually improving them in any way.

As Ronald D. Moore stated in the [Captains' Logs: The Unauthorized Complete Trek Voyages](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captains%27_Logs:_The_Unauthorized_Complete_Trek_Voyages) book:

> *...when you limit warp drive, the rug is being pulled out from under
>   Star Trek.*

Comment: ..."Out of Universe explanation" - which begs the question of why did they introduce it in the first place?

Comment: @komodosp - Because writers often write themselves in a corner without realising it. Luckily they can handwave these things away just as easily

Answer (score 0):

They very clearly stated that warp speed was restricted *in areas of space affected*- it was never restricted across all areas of space. It is assumed that any time they say "authorized to exceed warp speed restrictions" it's because they're in an area of space affected by the rifts.

Comment: The affected area seems to be extensive and cover all of the Alpha and Beta Quadrant powers inclusing the Federation and its near neighbours such as the Klingons, Romulans, Ferengi, etc; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Speed_limit